# subscribeTag is not working in windowsphone8

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

i am implementing TAG based push notification in windowsphone8 but my app is not able to register the TAG when i execute following code.

i have tried putting `subscribeTag` outside `onReadyToSubscribe` too but i am not getting anything no success , no failure , no nothing.

```
if (WL.Client.Push) {
            WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function() {

                WL.Client.Push.subscribeTag("RRNEWS", {
                    onSuccess: function () {

                        alert("Tag registered");

                    },
                    onFailure: function (e) {
                        alert("Tag registered failed" + JSON.stringify(e));
                    }
                });

            };
        }else{
               alert("not supported");
    }
```

i have register tag in `application-descriptor.xml` as follows

```
 <tags>
        <tag>
            <name>RRNEWS</name>
            <description>News</description>
        </tag>
    </tags>
```

here is the windowsphone8 entry

```
  <windowsPhone8 version="1.0">
        <uuid>6e043ba2-d382-4894-965f-47e08c24bd1e</uuid>
        <pushSender/>
    </windowsPhone8>
```

I run a tag based notification sample from [Tag Notification github](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/TagNotifications) and deployed it on my mobile first server 6.3

when i generated the windowspone8 build and run it into a device , it shows following results

```
1) isPushSupported -> True
2) isSubscribed    -> sample-tag1: false , sample-tag2: false
```

rest of the buttons are disabled

```
1) Subscribe to sample-tag2
2) Unsubscribe from sample-tag1
3) Unsubscribe from sample-tag2
```

then i tried removing `disabled` properties from html tag and try pressing 
`subscribe to sample-tag2` but nothing is happening.

Change is adapter code

```
function sendTagNotificationToWindows(applicationId, notificationText,notificationTags){

  var notificationOptions = {};
    var tags = notificationTags.split(","); 
    var notificationOptions = {};

    var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, 10);   
    notification.MPNS.raw = {};
    notification.MPNS.raw.payload = {"custom":"data"} ;

    notificationOptions.message = {};
    notificationOptions.target = {};
    notificationOptions.message.alert = JSON.stringify(notification);
    notificationOptions.target.tagNames = tags;


   // i have tried it with a notificationOptions too
    WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId, notification);


    return {
        result : "Notification sent to users subscribed to the tag(s): '" + JSON.stringify(notification) + "'."
    };

}
```

**Error**
when i pass only notification param it throws following error

```
   "Push Works Bad Request: FPWSE0005E: Invalid value was provided. Check the 'message' parameter value."
```

Comment: Does it also fail after adding the windowsphone8 environment to the tag notifications sample application, available here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/tag-based-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/ -- you can also compare your client-side implementation with that of the sample...

Comment: i compared with the version `https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/TagNotifications/tree/release71/apps/HybridTagNotifications` but there is no windowsphone8 build exist , but i compared with the common files and everything seems fine so far

Comment: i am using worklight 6.3

Comment: MobileFirst* 6.3; as said, you can **add the environment** and test. While the sample is for v7.1, you can simply copy over the implementation itself to yours. Looking at your partial code snippet it does not seem like the one in the provided sample.

Comment: can you please see my edits

Comment: If the subscribe to tag button is disabled, it means the application is not correctly configured to receive push notifications. See line #52: https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/TagNotifications/blob/release71/apps/HybridTagNotifications/common/js/main.js

Comment: I have configured it properly now i am able to see sample-tag1 and sample-tag1 on work light console and able to register tag on server too but the issue is when i invoke an adapter i am not able to receive it on windows device

Comment: Is MPNS correctly set in the adapter implementation? (search for "notification.MPNS" here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html?cp=SSHS8R_6.3.0%2F9-1-0-1-6&lang=en), also check that the app name is set as well in the adapter implementation (check the adapter in the sample project for an example).

Comment: do i need to set MPNS for tag based notification ? MPNS is for event source based right?

Comment: MPNS is for Windows Phone regardless of the type of notification - event source or tag, both go through MPNS.

Comment: `WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription ("MyEventSource", userID);` is asked for event source

Comment: Well, yes, but you're attempting tag notification so why are you looking at event source...

Comment: i looked for this ` notification.settings.mpns = {};` but cound not manage to call as it has `    WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId, notificationOptions);
`

Comment: Look at the sample, it needs to be done the same for MPNS as is set up for GCM and APNS...

Answer (score 0):

The [Tag notifications sample project](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/tag-based-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/) does not take into account the Windows Phone 8 environment. Here's what you need to add to the sample:

**application-descriptor.xml**
After adding the Windows Phone 8 environment, add an empty `pushSender` tag:

```
<windowsPhone8 version="1.0">
    <uuid>AUTOGENERATED-GUID-NUMBER-HERE</uuid>
    <pushSender/>
</windowsPhone8>
```

**PushAdater-impl.js**
Add the following to the function used for sending the notification.
For example, something like this:

```
function sendTagNotification(applicationId, notificationText, notificationTags) {
    var tags = notificationTags.split(",");
    var notificationOptions = {};

    notificationOptions.message = {};
    notificationOptions.message.alert = notificationText;

    notificationOptions.target = {};
    notificationOptions.target.tagNames = tags;

    notificationOptions.settings = {};
    notificationOptions.settings.mpns = {};
    notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast = {};

    notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast.text1 = "New notification";
    notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast.text2 = "You have a new notification";
    notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast.param = "/MainPage.xaml?value1=54321";

    WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId, notificationOptions);

    return {
        result : "Notification sent to users subscribed to the tag(s): '" + notificationTags + "'."
    };
}
```

`notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast` is needed so that when the application is closed (quit) or in the background, "toast" notification type will appear in the device.

Tapping on a toast notification launches the application. optional "param" field is used to pass on values that will be displayed once the application launches. The values set in the "param" of the toast can be retrieved [natively](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx) and displayed within the application.

Additional clarifications:

- When the app is open the raw notification type and the props and payload values can be seen on screen if used.
- When the app is in the background and tapping the notification there are two notification types that can be receive: toast or tile. Both open the application.
- When the app is in the background and tapping the app icon: 
  This means clicking the application tile. Application launches
- When the app is closed and tapping the notification: Tapping on the toast launches the application. Tapping on the application tile launches the application.
- When the app is closed and tapping the app icon: This means clicking the application tile. Application launches

I recommend to read the following MS documentation to understand what are the available notification types (Toast, Tile and Raw) and when to use them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx

Then search for "MPNS", "toast", "tile" or "raw" in the following user documentation topic (for `onMessage`) to see an example of how to set them up in your application: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.1.0%2F10-1-0-1-6&lang=en

Comment: should i pass notification variable directly into `WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId, notification);` becasue its not working this way

Comment: It is a variable you define... You can see it defined in the sample.

Comment: I have added a more complete example.

Comment: Do not use createDefault... it's not related at all when using tag notifications. Follow only the code in the sample application if using tag notifications.

Comment: i tried your code but still not getting any notification

Comment: Added additional clarifications.